Custom gutenberg block: window.wp.blockEditor returns undefined
I have an issue with creating a block. After I build my code, it always gives the n is undefined in the block editor when I try to put the block in with the console pointing the problem to the <edit> component. In the compiled code, n was equal to window.wp.blockEditor so I cannot understand what is wrong.
block.js:
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { PanelBody, Button, MediaUpload } from '@wordpress/components';

registerBlockType('comic-plugin/comic-block', {
    title: __("Comic Block", "comic-block"),
    icon: 'format-image',
    category: 'media',
    attributes: {
        images: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
        currentImageIndex: {
            type: 'number',
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    edit: function (props) {
        const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
        const { images, currentImageIndex } = attributes;

        const onSelectImage = function (media) {
            const imagesArray = media.map(function (item) {
                return item.url;
            });
            setAttributes({ images: imagesArray });
        };

        const onNextImage = function () {
            setAttributes({ currentImageIndex: currentImageIndex === images.length - 1 ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1 });
        };

        const onPrevImage = function () {
            setAttributes({ currentImageIndex: currentImageIndex === 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentImageIndex - 1 });
        };

        return (
        <>
            <div {...useBlockProps()}>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody title={__("Comic Settings", "comic-block")}>
                        <Button
                            className="button button-large"
                            onClick={() => setAttributes({ images: [], currentImageIndex: 0 })}
                        >
                            {__("Clear Images", "comic-block")}
                        </Button>
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>

                <MediaUpload
                    multiple={true}
                    gallery={true}
                    onSelect={onSelectImage}
                    render={(obj) => (
                        <Button
                            className="button button-large"
                            onClick={obj.open}
                        >
                            {__("Upload Images", "comic-block")}
                        </Button>
                    )}
                />
                {images.length > 0 && (
                    <div className="comic-images">
                        <img
                            src={images[currentImageIndex]}
                            alt="Comic Image"
                        />
                        <div className="comic-navigation">
                            <Button
                                onClick={onPrevImage}
                            >
                                {__("Previous", "comic-block")}
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                onClick={onNextImage}
                            >
                                {__("Next", "comic-block")}
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
        );
    },
    save: function (props) {
        const { attributes } = props;
        const { images } = attributes;

        const imageElements = images.map((image, index) => (
            <img
                key={index}
                src={image}
                alt="Comic Image"
                id={`comicpage-${index}`}
            />
        ));

        return (
            <div className="comic-images">
                {imageElements}
            </div>
        );
    },
});

block.json :
{
  "apiVersion": 2,
  "name": "comic-plugin/comic-block",
  "title": "Comic Block",
  "category": "media",
  "icon": "format-gallery",
  "attributes": {
    "images": {
      "type": "array",
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "supports": {
    "align": true
  },
  "editorScript": "file:./block.js",
  "viewScript": "file:./frontend.js"
}

I'm also providing the compiled block.js in case there are any specific issues with it:
(()=>{"use strict";const e=window.React,t=window.wp.blocks,c=window.wp.i18n,n=window.wp.blockEditor,o=window.wp.components;(0,t.registerBlockType)("comic-plugin/comic-block",{title:(0,c.__)("Comic Block","comic-block"),icon:"format-image",category:"common",attributes:{images:{type:"array",default:[]},currentImageIndex:{type:"number",default:0}},edit:function(t){const{attributes:a,setAttributes:i}=t,{images:m,currentImageIndex:l}=a;return(0,e.createElement)(e.Fragment,null,(0,e.createElement)(n.InspectorControls,null,(0,e.createElement)(o.PanelBody,{title:(0,c.__)("Comic Settings","comic-block")},(0,e.createElement)(o.Button,{className:"button button-large",onClick:()=>i({images:[],currentImageIndex:0})},(0,c.__)("Clear Images","comic-block")))),(0,e.createElement)(o.MediaUpload,{multiple:!0,gallery:!0,onSelect:function(e){const t=e.map((function(e){return e.url}));i({images:t})},render:t=>(0,e.createElement)(o.Button,{className:"button button-large",onClick:t.open},(0,c.__)("Upload Images","comic-block"))}),m.length>0&&(0,e.createElement)("div",{className:"comic-images"},(0,e.createElement)("img",{src:m[l],alt:"Comic Image"}),(0,e.createElement)("div",{className:"comic-navigation"},(0,e.createElement)(o.Button,{onClick:function(){i({currentImageIndex:0===l?m.length-1:l-1})}},(0,c.__)("Previous","comic-block")),(0,e.createElement)(o.Button,{onClick:function(){i({currentImageIndex:l===m.length-1?0:l+1})}},(0,c.__)("Next","comic-block")))))},save:function(t){const{attributes:c}=t,{images:n}=c,o=n.map(((t,c)=>(0,e.createElement)("img",{key:c,src:t,alt:"Comic Image",id:`comicpage-${c}`})));return(0,e.createElement)("div",{className:"comic-images"},o)}})})();

I didn't provide frontend.js as I don't think it's relevant.
Imported the block like that in a plugin (but I doubt it's relevant):
function comic_block() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__. '/comic-block' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'comic_block' );


some notes: you'll want to use state rather than block attributes for the current image otherwise as you scroll through images that gets saved and applied to the frontend too. You should also consider using child image blocks instead of maintaining an array of images. This way you get all the ordering/sorting/insertion/removal/movement controls of the native block editor without having to build it all yourself from scratch. The core gallery block made this change and it greatly simplified the block. There's a very high chance your entire block could be replaced with a gallery block variant

It seems like your JavaScript file is being enqueued before the Core block-editor.js file. Are you compiling the JavaScript with the wordpress-scripts package? it should generate an *.asset.php file alongside the block.js script. It should have a dependencies array which should include wp-block-editor. This would then cause the file to load after block-editor.js which should mitigate your problem.

@Wongjn That was it. I have forgotten to transfer over that asset file (don't ask why). But now I get a problem which I find way too often which is Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. and Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string both in the edit component. Any idea what could the issue?

I believe it is because you are trying to use the MediaUpload from @wordpress/components but MediaUpload does not exist.

@Wongjn Wow, thanks a ton. It works like a charm now.
